# Compare number in one cell to multiple cells and give out nearest number

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dew-CLxHvMW2BgI9axdJTEI-2CezTx7k6Vt1R48mwgA/edit?usp=sharing

Above is the sample sheet. I need a formula in `K` cell

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following formulas

Closest minimum value

```
=MINIFS(A2:E2, A2:E2, ">=" & G2)
```

Closest maximum value

```
=MAXIFS(A2:E2, A2:E2, "<=" & G2)
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`MINIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014063)
- [`MAXIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013817)

Comment: Welcome. 
Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Can you also help me out how I can output the cell reference in another column? I mean in J cell, I need E2 to be output.

Comment: If I understand you correctly: "*...in J cell, I need E2 to be output*". In cell `J2` use `=E2`. If not, please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dew-CLxHvMW2BgI9axdJTEI-2CezTx7k6Vt1R48mwgA/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the link with permissions